# Node inconsistent with parents error when using dwiener distribution JAGS

Tags: distribution, jags

I'm currently trying to test the dwiener distribution on my reaction time data (obtained from a two choice bandit task) before inserting it into a larger model. Here is my basic model here:

```
for (j in 1:N_SUBJECTS) {  
  a1[j] ~ dunif(0,5)
  t1[j] ~ dunif(0,1)
  v1[j] ~ dnorm(0,1)

  for (t in 1:N_TRIALS[j]) {

rt[j,t] ~ dwiener(a1[j],t1[j],0.5,v1[j])
      
  } #end of trial loop
  
    } #end of subject loop
```

The data I've input to JAGS is number of subjects (N_SUBJECTS), number of trials per subject (N_TRIALS[j]) and rt[j,t] (reaction times in the format subjects x trials). I've coded the reaction times to be in seconds. The reaction times associated with choice 1 are coded to be negative and those associated with choice 2 are positive, as stipulated by this paper on the dwiener distribution: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/1hn8q7d7

I fit the model to data using the code below:

```
params <- c("a1", "t1", "v1")

samps <- jags(jagsdata,inits=NULL, params,
              model.file ="sqd_ddmonly.txt", n.chains=1, n.iter=2000, 
              n.burnin=500, n.thin=1, DIC=T)
```

But unfortunately I'm receiving this error:

```
Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  Error in node rt1[1,3]
Node inconsistent with parents
```

As it's quite a simple model I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I usually see this problem arise when initial values have very low prior probability.  Providing reasonable starting values might solve the problem.

Comment: Seems to have worked when I set prior values to be:  a1 = 1.0, t1 = 0.001, and v1 = 0. Thank you!